# Integrando APP de Laravel con Mercadopago

Tags: php, laravel, mercadopago

Estoy teniendo un problema al momento de crear mi preferencia de pago, tal problema es un

> "Params Error" 400.

Formulario con el cual envío los productos del carrito a mi controlador:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{!! route('payment.process') !!}" method="post">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input type="hidden" name="ctoken" id="ctoken" value="{!! $cart_token !!}">
  <input type="submit" name="pagar" value="Pagar" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-sm">
</form>
```

Controlador en cuestión:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Models\Cart;
use Exception;
use MP;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * Display a listing of the resource.
   *
   * @return Response
   */
  public function process(Request $request)
  {

    $mp = new MP (env('OCULTO'), env('OCULTO'));

    $user = auth()->user();

    $preferenceData = [
        'external_reference' => $request->ctoken,
        'payer'              => [
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'date_created' => $user->created_at
        ]
    ];

    $entries = Cart::where('session_id', '=', $request->ctoken)->get();
    foreach ($entries as $e):
        $preferenceData['items'][] = [
            'id'          => $e->product_id,
            'category_id' => 'zapato',
            'title'       => $e->product_name,
            'description' => 'esta es la descripción del zapato',
            'picture_url' => 'https://placehold.it/600x600',
            'quantity'    => $e->qty,
            'currency_id' => 'VEF',
            'unit_price'  => $e->price,
        ];
    endforeach;

    $preference = $mp->create_preference($preferenceData);

    // return init point to be redirected
    //return $preference['response']['init_point'];
    return dd($preferenceData);

  }
}
```

En los parámetros ocultos tengo las credenciales proporcionadas por mercadopago.

Comment: Que respuesta obtienes al ejecutar el código?

Comment: "Params Error" 400.

Comment: No pongas las credenciales creales, pero me gustaría saber como las estas poniendo, porque estoy viendo de que estas usando el helper env() entonces las credenciales no deberían estar en la clase sino en el archivo .env